# Content of Header need to be update while router navigate in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a HeaderComponent Having Some Content..
On the base of route I need to `[ngSwitch]` some content like
in Home I want to show one Link but Other than Home Page, I like to show more links on header.
How can I update or subscribe to router
I have done `this._router.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));` also but not able to get route Information...

Comment: Which version of router you using. If @angular/router 3.0.0.beta2 then use this._router.events.subscribe( (e)=> { if(e instanceof NavigationEnd){//check URL and run your logic } });

Answer (score 0):

you can provide service for switching header states, and subscribe to its changes like I did:

```
<pre><code>
export class HeaderService {
    getOptions () {
        return headerOptions;
    }
    setHeaderOptions(options: any) {
        headerOptions.next({
            showLogo: options.showLogo,
            showLabel: options.showLabel,
            label: options.label,
            showAuthBtn: options.showAuthBtn,
            showCloseBtn: options.showCloseBtn,
            showMenuBtn: options.showMenuBtn,
            showByTagsBtn: options.showByTagsBtn,
            ....
        });
    }
}
</code></pre>
```

and each @Component constructor function will set options :

```
<pre><code>
headerService.setHeaderOptions({showHeader: true,
            showLogo: true,
            showLabel: false,
            showAuthBtn: true,
            showCloseBtn: false,
            showMenuBtn: true,
            showByTagsBtn: false})
</code></pre>
```

and your HeaderComponent should subscribe to this changes

```
<pre><code>
checkOptions() {
    this.hederService.getOptions().subscribe((headerOptions: HeaderOptions) => {
      this.options = headerOptions;
      this.checkAuthorization();
    });
  }
</code></pre>
```

Comment: also you can call setHeaderOptions in header itself 

this.router['routerEvents'].subscribe((event: Event) => {
         //here you will have url and other router params 
      });